# Proof of being martingale

Tags: local-martingales

We have given number $1<p< \infty$, $K>0$ and continuous local martingale $M$ such that $\mathbb{E}|M_{\tau}|^p \le K$ for every limited stopping time $\tau$. Show that $M$ is martingale.

Please help me, I have a big problem with solving this task. I don't know how to even start it.

Comment: where have you used $p$ (I guess it comes from the $p$-norm though)

Comment: Thanks,  I ommited it

Comment: Do You have any idea how to help me?

Comment: it is a rather standard result, just check for example *every bounded local martingale is a martingale* - you should be able to find a lot of material.

Comment: yes you're right: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~alanb/stoc-calc.pdf - theorem 5.2. But I find it hard to use it in this task and WRITE it down to be properly done

Comment: is it just: there exists $\tau_n$ localization sequence such that: $\mathbb{E}(M_t^{\tau_n}|F_s)=M^{\tau_n}_s$ so we have $\mathbb{E}(M_{t \wedge {\tau_n}}|F_s)=M_{{\tau_n}\wedge s}$ thanks to $\mathbb{E}|M_{\tau}|^p \le K$ it convergences to $\mathbb{E}(M_t|F_s)=M_s$